# Desabilitar cache do css e de imagens no navegador

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Recentemente, desenvolvi um projeto que teve algumas mudanças drásticas em relação ao seu design, principalmente, pelo lado do css e das imagens. Nisso, acessando ele em algumas máquinas, verifiquei que para visualizar o seu novo design era necessário limpar o cache (ctrl + f5). Entretanto, pensando pelo lado do usuário, nós que somos de TI sabemos o que fazer mas o usuário não. Dessa forma gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de desativar o salvamento automático do CSS e das imagens em cache.

Comment: Somente limpando o cache dos navegadores: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300400/google-chrome-css-doesnt-update-unless-clear-cache

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No ASP.NET MVC, isto é feito através de um filtro global usando o [`OutputCacheAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). O código a seguir pode ser colocado no `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute { VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true });
    ...
}
```

`NoStore` indica ao navegador por cabeçalho, usando a propriedade `Cache-Control: no-store` que nada deve ser mantido em cache (JS e CSS).

Você pode decorar seus *Controllers* individualmente, se não for do seu desejo desabilitar a *cache* no sistema inteiro:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public class MeuController : Controller { ... }
```

Ou *Actions*:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Index() { ... }
```

Comment: +1 agora está explicado por que não tem uma meta-tag para isto, tem um header.

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Zack, infelizmente não tenho conhecimento de nenhuma `metatag` que force a limpesa do cache.

porém você pode usar um `hack` para forçar a atualização do aquivo. O mais simples seria adicionar uma informação extra ao link para o arquivo `.js` ou `.css`, seja alterando o nome ou adicionando uma queryString.

Digamos que você tenha o seguinte arquivo `.css`: `\Content\style.css`, você pode assumir que apartir de agora esta seja a versão 1 do arquivo, então você pode linkar ele na pagina usando uma das seguintes alternativas:

```
<link src="\Content\style-1.0.0.css" /> <!-- é necessario renomear o arquivo -->
<link src="\Content\style.css?v=1.0.0" /> <!-- não é necessario renomear o arquivo -->
```

No exemplo acima estou passando uma versão, que você poderá alterar manualmente, porem você pode usar outra informação, como o `md5` do arquivo ou o `epoch` time da ultima modificação.

Tanto o `epoch` quanto o `md5` podem ser obtidos em runtime utilizando algum helper na sua linguagem de preferencia, neste caso o seu link ficaria assim:

```
<link src="\Content\style.css?t=1468933059" />
<link src="\Content\style.css?h=2e9d6b2fddb91d78a0f3f07194c98e9e" />
```

lembrando que caso tenha alguma duvida de como automatizar à geração destes dados, você deve abrir uma nova pergunta com um escopo mais definito e informar quais tecnologias/ferramentas você pode utilizar (`C#`, `Node`, `PHP`, `Gulp`, `Grunt`, etc).

**EDIT**

Caso você queira realmente desativar o Cache, você deve utilizar a solução sugerida pelo @CiganoMorrisonMendez (que na minha opinião é a que melhor responde ao seu problema).

Porém lembre-se que tanto o cache no cliente (navegador) e no servidor podem melhorar e muito a experiencia do usuário e aliviar à carga ao servidor, então ao manter o cache ativo e usar à técnica acima, você poderá aproveitar os benefícios do cache e garantir que os usuários sempre verão a versão mais recente dos seus arquivos.

Comment: Toby, [veja isto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez tinha lido apenas a pergunta e não tinha prestado atenção as tags, acabei por dá uma resposta genérica, mas já que se trata de as `asp-net mvc` então está mais do que certo.